# Using e.values with onFormSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I'm brand new at this so please excuse me if this is a silly question.

I'm using google script to carry out a change based on the submitted answer from a google form.
I've got a test function I've been using to get it right in the script editor and it works perfectly.
When using the onFormSubmit trigger instead though, getting the variable result from e.values, it isn't doing anything.  I've defined the trigger for the project and can see that confirmed in the 'Current Project's Triggers' window so it can't be that.

This is the test function code:

```
function Test_form_submit() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Group Totals")
   SpreadsheetApp.flush()
   var their_choice1 = "Group 5: Thursday 6-8pm"
   var r = find_limits("C3:E7", their_choice1)
   var count = r[0]
   var limit = r[1] 
   check_availability("545507554", count, limit, their_choice1)

}
```

This is my trigger function code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Group Totals")
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  var their_choice1 = e.values[3]
  var r = find_limits("C3:E7", their_choice1)
  var count = r[0]
  var limit = r[1] 
  check_availability("545507554", count, limit, their_choice1)

}
```

The choice of theirs I'm wanting is in column D on the spreadsheet so I believe e.values[3] is the right thing to use.
I can't understand why nothing is happening.

I tried adding a line of logger.log(e.values[3]) as well but the log is blank when I look.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to Amit's answer, you can check all the values and parameters returned in the `eventInfo` coming with the onFormSubmit trigger by using a statement like this :

```
  Logger.log(e);
```

This will show something like this :

[image]

(the values shown here come from an unused form that I had with "garbage" values ;-) but it is sufficient to actually see the structure.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I added this line but still the logging output is blank.   There's definitely data in the form though and I've definitely defined the trigger.  I'm baffled!

Comment: I'd suggest you change your trigger to fire a new function that would have only this Logger.log(e) line just to test that the link between SS and form is actually working. Please keep this post update with the result. thx

Comment: I added a new function, deleted the old trigger, set up a new one for the new function with the only line in it being Logger.log(e) and the log output is still blank!

Comment: Hmmmm... embarrassing:-)  maybe trying a brand new form?  Could you share a form / spreadsheet for me to test?

Comment: I'll be away for a while but will be back in a couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks!  What's your google account to share with?  Couldn't find it on your profile anywhere

Comment: I set up a copy of the form, created the responses spreadsheet new and the code copied from the previous, and lo, I have log output!

Comment: He he... great!  Good luck :-)

Comment: I still only get log output if it's in a function on its own though - when I put it into the normal onFormSubmit(e) function, no output again.  This is driving me potty now

Comment: Well I finally got there.  Turned out it was in the check_availability function I was calling.
By a very slow process of elimination, I had to remove the variables I'd set for the spreadsheet and the sheet that I wasn't then using in the function.
No idea why removing these 2 variables made the logging work and made the whole thing work, but it did!
Thanks so much for your help Serge, I'd have come to a standstill without your help!

Comment: Sorry, not home now...my email is sergegabet and is a Gmail account :-)  - be back later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.namedValues to get the submitted value for any particular column.

```
e.namedValues["FULL COLUMN NAME"].toString();
```

Comment: The column name isn't unique though so I can't use this

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has tried using the same methods above with no luck, I found this link https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5325. To summarize:

```
function runonformsubmit(e){
    var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
    var item1 = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
    //OR to get the title of the question
    var title1 = itemResponses[0].getItem().getTitle();
}
```

I've successfully used this model to extract the responses. Here is a sample of the code that I currently use:

```
function createClientDefaultURLs(e){
    var clientResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
    var clientFName = clientResponses[0].getResponse();
    var clientLName = clientResponses[1].getResponse();
    var companyName = clientResponses[2].getResponse();
    var companyAddress = clientResponses[3].getResponse();
    var clientEmail = clientResponses[4].getResponse();
}
```

Hope that helps someone else figure out how to extract the responses from the form submissions.